# Save android canvas as svg

Tags: android, svg, android-canvas

I am trying to make a signature pad for android and the output should be svg. I am using this library now: https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad 
Alternately, I can use canvas. But the major issue is converting it into svg. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Not easily.  You might need to submit a feature request to the library authors, or modify the library yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the implementation of `SignaturePad` class, generating a SVG path from the `mPoints` array and apply a Bezier transformation to the path itself: http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-svg-cubic-curves/.

Anyway, if you send me a pull request I'll be happy to include that new feature into the library.

Comment: This is now implemented in [v1.1.0](https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad/blob/v1.1.0/signature-pad/src/main/java/com/github/gcacace/signaturepad/utils/SvgBuilder.java)